# Mapping dictionary as new column efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have the following df,

```
d = {'col1':['cat','apple','banana','dog','pen']}
df= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

that gives

```
     col1
0     cat
1   apple
2  banana
3     dog
4     pen
```

I want to make a dictionary and map it as a new column to my df, such that I get the following output:

```
     col1   col2
0     cat    pet
1   apple  fruit
2  banana  fruit
3     dog    pet
4     pen  thing
```

I have made the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
  "pet": ['cat','dog'],
  "fruit": ['apple','banana'],
  "thing": 'pen'}
```

but not sure how to implement it as above, a tedious way of doing this is making one by one dictionary and then use map as:

```
di = {"cat": "pet", "dog": "pet", "apple": "fruit", "banana": "fruit", "pen":"thing"}
```

and

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(di)
```

but this is not the most efficient way I suppose. I wonder how one does this task more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a list of tuples and then create the dataframe from that list. It would be simpler if all of your values in the dict are lists instead of having strings for single values.

```
data = []
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    if isinstance(v, str):
        data.append((v, k))
    else:
        for vv in v:
            data.append((vv, k))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to *explode* the lists:

```
# transform all values to list
dictionary = {k: v if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for k, v in dictionary.items()}

# then explode the dictionary
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map({v: k for k, vs in dictionary.items() for v in vs})
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     col1   col2
0     cat    pet
1   apple  fruit
2  banana  fruit
3     dog    pet
4     pen  thing
```

An alternative using only pandas (although more cumbersome):

```
# convert to Series
res = pd.DataFrame(data=list(dictionary.values()),
                   index=dictionary.keys()).stack().droplevel(-1).to_frame('vs').reset_index().set_index('vs').squeeze()

# use map with Series as parameter
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(res)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     col1   col2
0     cat    pet
1   apple  fruit
2  banana  fruit
3     dog    pet
4     pen  thing
```

Comment: Some of the values are strings, others are lists.